# ClassCastException when sending ActiveMQ message with Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I am trying to send a message to an ActiveMQ queue, but I am getting a `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.UUID cannot be cast to java.lang.String`. I have been trying to look up how to solve this issue but no real answers are online. I am sending it with a private method as such:

```
private void sendToHosts( Map<Object, Object> msg, String[] hosts )
{
    Arrays.stream( hosts )
        .forEach( host -> {

            ProducerTemplate template = camelContext.createProducerTemplate();

            template.setDefaultEndpointUri("direct:com.example.updatehost." + host);


            try {
                template.sendBody( msg ); //throwing ClassCastException
            } 
            catch( Exception e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    });
```

where the camelContext is injected using spring, and I know it is running.

I know that ActiveMQ is setup properly as the only way I get into this method is if I recieve a message from another queue, and I am trying to relay this message after doing some methods above, but I am not modifying the message in any way.

The message has a `Map<UUID,Object>` in it, which is where my suspicion is to the underlying issue. 
Partial Stacktrace:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.UUID cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.String  at
>   org.apache.activemq.util.MarshallingSupport.marshalPrimitiveMap(MarshallingSupport.java:61)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.util.MarshallingSupport.marshalPrimitive(MarshallingSupport.java:151)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.util.MarshallingSupport.marshalPrimitiveMap(MarshallingSupport.java:64)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQMapMessage.storeContent(ActiveMQMapMessage.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQMapMessage.copy(ActiveMQMapMessage.java:121)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQMapMessage.copy(ActiveMQMapMessage.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.send(ActiveMQSession.java:1773)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducer.send(ActiveMQMessageProducer.java:289)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducer.send(ActiveMQMessageProducer.java:224)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledProducer.send(PooledProducer.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledProducer.send(PooledProducer.java:62)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doSend(JmsTemplate.java:635)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate.doSend(JmsConfiguration.java:343)

Has anyone encountered this, and then found a way to get around the `ClassCastException`? I find it weird that when marshalling, they expect it to be a `Map<String,Object>` and don't support `Map<Object,Object>`.

I 100% need the `Map<UUID,Object>` in the message as well, Don't want to convert the `UUID` to a `String` representation, as I am doing some stuff with Hibernate that requires it to be a `UUID` later down the road.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More information can be found here: http://camel.apache.org/jms or here http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html

> **Message Bodies**
>
> The JMS API defines five types of message body:
>
> - Stream - A StreamMessage object's message body contains a stream of    primitive values in the Java programming language ("Java
>     primitives"). It is filled and read sequentially.
> - ***Map - A MapMessage object's message body contains a set of name-value    pairs, where names are `String` objects, and values are
>     Java    primitives. The entries can be accessed sequentially or
>     randomly by    name. The order of the entries is undefined.***
> - Text - A TextMessage object's message body contains a    java.lang.String object. This message type can be used to transport
>     plain-text messages, and XML messages.
> - Object - An ObjectMessage object's message body contains a    Serializable Java object.
> - Bytes - A BytesMessage object's message body contains a stream of    uninterpreted bytes. This message type is for literally encoding a
>     body to match an existing message format. In many cases, it is
>     possible to use one of the other body types, which are easier to use. 
>     Although the JMS API allows the use of message properties with byte
>     messages, they are typically not used, since the inclusion of
>     properties may affect the format.

I think, you have to convert the `UUID` to a `String`.

Comment: Quite right, JMS MapMessage is Map<String, Object> with limits on the Object, you need to handle this in the code before the send

Comment: Instead of sending in the method handler for the message as I was doing, I ended up using the `multicast()` method of `RouteBuilder` to send the message and used a `Predicate` to filter the messages as necissary. Working like a charm now that I am doing it outside of the method.